# What are the benefits of using A B C as table alias in a SQL query just based on the order the tables are added in the FROM clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, alias

We sent some of our new starters off for some basic SQL training and they came back renaming tables as A for the first table and B for the second and so on. One of them said they were told: 
 - It was quicker to type 
 - If you use the starting letter then you run into issues when you have tables starting with the same name

In my opinion this seriously sacrifices the readability of the query and I'm probably going to be the one reviewing the code they write. I just want to make sure I'm not missing something before I tell them to either use the first letter and number if there are multiple tables or just an abbreviated version of the table name. In most cases the table names are only 5-8 letters long so I'd prefer they use the full name than an alias that doesn't describe the table in any way.

Are there any other benefits?

Comment: That kind of lazy crap drives me mad. Name your aliases something short and descriptive so I don't have to be all like "d... d... that was the aggregate on customer invoice with the terrible case statement" EVERY TIME I see it laced throughout the query. Just call it `ci_agg` or even `cia` or `ci`. Throw me some kind of bone.

Comment: I would argue that using a, b, c is a horrible idea. This question will most certainly be closed as being primarily opinion based but the people providing that training need to be taken out back and beaten. It is a serious PITA to debug queries like that, especially when you get to a dozen or more tables. Aaron Bertrand has a great article on this topic. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Comment: I personally like an alias even over a short table name. It makes the code less lengthy and easier to follow. Once you start using aliases in a system you will come up with a way of being consistent. That means Customer is always c or similar.

Comment: I just want to add too, that SQL is very verbose and that verbosity should be used to the advantage of the person writing it. Be explicit as much as possible. Don't cut corners on naming. Don't be afraid of adding more characters. The parser can handle it and the poor schmuck that is awestruck at the crappy SQL you are sending into their system and is devoting an hour to refactoring it will thank you for it, even while they are shaking their head at your garbage logic. Also, I'm angry today. Also, also, I completely agree with standardizing short names @SeanLange. `c` for customer is good.

Comment: And `c` for `itemized_customer_rebates_aggregate_archive` is terrible.

Comment: I agree there isn't any advantage to using just A, B, C... You could have a table names Employee_Data and Employee_OffSetData and something like E or F can get annoying. I would at least use ED or EOSD so it is easy to follow which one is which. I have had requests come in to me before and said I wont work on it until they fix their aliases.

Comment: However...even crappy aliases like a, b, c are better than the full name all over the place. [dbo].[Customers].[CustomerNum] makes me want to slit my throat. But with decent aliases that becomes c.CustomerNum which is clear and concise.

Comment: when SQL query are computer generated this kind of aliasing helps to do complex query on some databases. When you hit the wall with database only accepting less than 64ko query, aliasing is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

well, I would like to point two facts with examples

1.-   select * from pupils pup inner join pupils pup2 on pup.id=pup2.otherId. In this example, I know exactly what I am linking because I am using the same table twice, really useful for queries where the same table is linked twice at least.

```
2.- readability is not a problem if you chose well the alias:

 select * from pupils pup inner join parents  payees on 
  parents.id=pupils.parentid
  inner join parents tutors on pupils.tutorid=tutors.id
```

In this case, readability is not an issue and I still know and distinguish which are the parents who pay and the tutors or legal guardians.